# SQL query about union and concat

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to select union values from two table and also add prefix to the  result values. 
Eg:-

```
select concat('Source-',id), concat('Source-',name)
from src_tbl where id IS not NULL and name IS not NULL    
UNION
select concat('Destination-',id), concat('Destination-',name)
from dstn_table where id IS not NULL and name IS not NULL  
order by name
```

Union and concat is working separately but wen I am combining it's not working and throwing error "that name is not found from tables on both sides of union". The column is present though

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

use alias in 1st table column name

```
  select concat('Source-',id) source_id,
         concat('Source-',name) name
         from src_tbl where id IS not NULL and name IS not NULL    
         UNION
  select concat('Destination-',id),
         concat('Destination-',name)
         from dstn_table where id IS not NULL and name IS not NULL  
         order by name
```

Comment: Thanku . Working fine

Comment: @PayalBhakat you welcome happy to know its working :)

Comment: @PayalBhakat as its working fine you can accept it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to define alias for column name

```
select concat('Source-',id) as id, concat('Source-',name) as name from src_tbl where id IS not NULL and name IS not NULL    
UNION
select concat('Destination-',id), concat('Destination-',name) from dstn_table where id IS not NULL and name IS not NULL order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` clause refers to the result of both queries. Add aliases there and you should be good to go:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Source-',id), CONCAT('Source-', name) AS name
FROM   src_tbl
WHERE  id IS NOT NULL AND name IS NOT NULL    
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('Destination-',id), CONCAT('Destination-',name) AS name
FROM   dstn_table
WHERE  id IS NOT NULL AND name IS NOT NULL  
ORDER BY name
```